# Когда нужно использовать Enum?

Tags: java, android, enum

Всем привет. В проектировании приложения часто попадаются статические элементы, например, кнопки нижней навигации, отвечающие за смену фрагмента, списки категорий, чекбоксы, типы сортировок, кнопки соц.сетей и т.д. Везде использую enum. Например, создаю enum для кнопок нижней нааигации и "захардкоживаю" классы фрагментов, для кнопок соц. сетей - енумы с их ссылками, названиями, ссылками на картинки в R.drawable. Для сортировок (скажем из БД) - тоже прямо в полях делаю специфичные экземпляры для ОРМ типа `SortedBy`. Вообщем, для всех статичных данных использую Enum-ы. Буквально весь проект ими уже кишит.

Я считаю что енумы полезны в случае реальной схожести. Но, сейчас, все больше появляются расширения, к примеру, при переходе на определенный фрагмент требуется кидать инфу об этом в аналитику, причем, для одного определенного фрагмента. Вообшем, сейчас вся эта красота превращается в уродство. Для тех фрагментов к которым не припилена аналитика я в полях приписываю null и потом на них делаю проверки.

Скажите, хорошо ли вообще использовать енумы? Сейчас лучше все переписать (на что?) или дальше писать костыли?

Когда **действительно** нужно их использовать? И надо ли вообще?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Enum` следует использовать тогда, когда вам нужно а)конечное, б)заранее определенное, в)адекватно именованное множество г)уникальных значений.

Например у светофора всего три сигнала (утрируя).

```
public enum TrafficLight{
    RED, YELLOW, GREEN;
}
```

Теперь, задавая текущую горящую секцию вы(ваш коллега) сможете использовать только вот этот заданный набор цветов и не сможете задать, например `TrafficLight.BLUE`

```
Lights lights = new Lights();
lights.current = TrafficLight.BLUE; // Ошибка момента компиляции
                                    // lights.current имеет тип TrafficLight
```

`Enum` хороши для создания коротких словарей (например статусов чего-то) или в качестве флагов (если не предполагается их комбинировать). Пихать везде и по любому поводу их, конечно, не нужно.

Кроме того, `enum`-ы далеко не бесплатны. Обратите внимание, что в Android SDK их практически нет, а вместо них используются числовые константы. [Почитайте, почему было сделано так.](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3)

Только не бросайтесь изничтожать `enum`-ы  в пользу числовых констант - это далеко не всегда оправдано. :) Например, если мы заменим класс цветов светофора по примеру гугла на числа:

```
public class TrafficLight{
    public static final Integer RED = 1;
    public static final Integer YELLOW = 2;
    public static final Integer GREEN = 3;
}
```

То никакой защиты от такого косяка не будет:

```
Lights lights = new Lights();
lights.current = 4; // Хреннайдибельная ошибка в рантайме
                    // lights.current имеет тип Integer - ни о чем не говорит
```